# codeigniter - not routing to subfolder controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter based code which runs very well in a LAMP installation in my ubuntu machine, we moved over the code to a windows based xampp installation.

The controller structure is like this

```
application 
           - controllers
                 -API
                     - test.php(a test controller)
                 -test
                     - testmore.php (a test controller)
                 -test.php (a test controller, and this one works only)
```

when we try to access application/controllers/test.php like `http://localhost/<appname>/test` it works well; but when we try to access other controllers like `http://localhost<appname>/API/test/<functionName>` it says "404 Page not found"

Please help.

Comment: Are you removing index.php using htaccess? If so, htaccess can't run in  windows server. So try url with index.php

Comment: I think you should change "API" to api

Comment: @kumar_v .htaccess runs just fine on Windows, it cannot run on IIS

Comment: You would have to show us your `routes.php` and .htaccess files before anyone can make an informed recommendation

Comment: What are you replacing `<appname>` with?

Comment: what does your routes config file look like?

Comment: this is my .htaccess code 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: this is my routes.php code
$route['default_controller'] = "test";
$route['1.0/supports/support']="API/supports/support";
$route['1.0/(:any)']="API/$1";
$route['1.0/(:any)/(:any)']="API/$1/$2";
$route['getupdate.mtnl']="API/getupdate";
$route['Activation/Activation.ashx']="API/Activation";

$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: <appname> is the folder name of my app, i don't think it creates any issue

Comment: For future reference, please update your original post with new information because it's not worth the hassle of reading large chunks of code from a comment. Also if you want the attention of a specific user then you can write `@MonkeyZeus` and it will alert me of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right outside the test folder there is a test.php controller, which might just be confusing your routing, get rid of it, i think it'll work